# asp:checkbox always sends false

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I have the following issue, i want to disable or enable a control in my asp form by using asp:checkbox but when i click on the checkbox to change the checked state to true or false, it will always send "false"

```
  <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Registration.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-size: medium;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: x-large;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            font-size: medium;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-size: x-large;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            border-style: outset;
            border-width: 3px;
        }
        .auto-style8 {
            width: 351px;
        }
        .auto-style9 {
            width: 344px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">



     <div id="registration" class="auto-style2">
          <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
          <br />
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>Employees in the database:</td>
                  <td>

                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upddlEmployee" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                       <asp:DropDownList 
                           ID="drpEmployee" 
                           runat="server" 
                           Height="30px" 
                           Width="175px" 
                           BackColor="White" 
                           CssClass="auto-style2" 
                           ForeColor="#000099"
                           AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="drpEmployee" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>


                  </td>
              </tr>

          </table>
          <br />
          <br />
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Employee ID:*" Width="300px" 
            Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" Height="31px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">
                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployee_id" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style5" Height="30px" Width="200px" AutoPostBack ="true" OnTextChanged ="txtEmployeeUser_id_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                              <span class="auto-style6">
                              <asp:label 
                                  ID="lblEmployeeID" 
                                  runat="server" 
                                  Text =""
                                  InitialValue="" Width="229px"></asp:label>
                              </span>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8"><span class="auto-style6">
          <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="First Name:*" Width="300px" 
            Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" height="30px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
         </span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="auto-style5" height="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                  </td>
                  <td>
         <span class="auto-style6">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ErrorMessage="First Name Required" CssClass="auto-style3" Width="300px"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         </span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">

          <span class="auto-style6">

        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text=" Last Name:*" Width="300px" 
            Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" height="30px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
         </span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="auto-style5" height="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                  </td>
                  <td>
         <span class="auto-style6">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtLastName" ErrorMessage="Last Name Required" CssClass="auto-style3" Width="300px"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
         </span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">

          <span class="auto-style6">


              <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text=" User Name:*" Width="300px" 
            Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" height="30px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
         </span></td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">
                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style5" height="30px" Width="200px" AutoPostBack ="True" OnTextChanged="txtEmployeeUser_id_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                          <Triggers>
                              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtUserName" EventName="TextChanged" />
                          </Triggers>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>
                  </td>
                  <td>
         <span class="auto-style6">
                              <asp:label 
                                  ID="lblUsernameCheck" 
                                  runat="server" 
                                  Text =""
                                  InitialValue="" Width="229px"></asp:label>
         </span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">
         <span class="auto-style6">
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Regular Time:" Width="300px" 
            Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" height="30px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
         </span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">
                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegularTime" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style5" height="30px" TextMode="Number" Width="200px" AutoPostBack ="True" OnTextChanged ="txtRegularTime_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                          <Triggers>
                              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtRegularTime" EventName="TextChanged" />
                          </Triggers>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>
                  </td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">
         <span class="auto-style6">
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Double Time:" Width="300px" 
            Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" height="30px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
         </span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">
                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtDoubleTime" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style5" height="30px" TextMode="Number" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>
                  </td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">
         <span class="auto-style6">
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Part Time:" Width="300px" 
            Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" height="30px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
         </span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">
                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartTime" runat="server" Width="200px" TextMode="Number" CssClass="auto-style5" height="30px" AutoPostBack ="True" OnTextChanged ="txtPartTime_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                          <Triggers>
                              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtPartTime" EventName="TextChanged" />
                          </Triggers>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>
                  </td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">
         <span class="auto-style6">
        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Over time:" Width="300px" 
            Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" height="30px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
         </span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">
                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtOverTime" runat="server" Width="200px" TextMode="Number" CssClass="auto-style5" height="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>
                  </td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=" Password:*" Width="231px" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" height="30px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>


                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel8" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkChecked"  />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="CheckedChanged" ControlID ="CheckBox1" />
                        </Triggers>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>

                 </td>

                  <td class="auto-style9">

                      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel9" runat="server">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Width="200px" TextMode="Password" CssClass="auto-style5" height="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>

                  </td>
                  <td>
         <span class="auto-style6">
             <asp:CustomValidator ID="txtpasswordValidator" runat="server" 
                 ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="Password Required" CssClass="auto-style3" Width="300px"
                 OnServerValidate="txtpassword_ServerValidate" >
             </asp:CustomValidator>
         </span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">
         <span class="auto-style6">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=" Confirm Password:*" Width="300px" 
            Font-Bold="True" CssClass="auto-style7" height="30px" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
         </span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel10" runat="server">
                          <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmpassword" runat="server" Width="200px" TextMode="Password" CssClass="auto-style5" height="30px"></asp:TextBox> 
                          </ContentTemplate>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>

                  </td>
                  <td> 
         <span class="auto-style6"> 
        <asp:CustomValidator 
            ID="CustomValidator1" 
            runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtConfirmpassword"
            ErrorMessage="Password mismatch" 
            OnServerValidate="txtConfirmpassword_ServerValidate"
            CssClass="auto-style3" 
            Width="300px"></asp:CustomValidator>
         </span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">


                      <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                  </td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="auto-style9">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
         <br />

          <span class="auto-style6">
             &nbsp;<br class="auto-style3" />
         </span><span class="auto-style4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span class="auto-style6">
        <br class="auto-style3" />



        <Table runat="server" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button 
                        ID="btnConfirmPassword" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text="Confirm Registration" 
                        onclick="Button1_Click" 
                        Font-Bold="True" 
                        Font-Size="X-Large" 
                        Height="50px"
                        Width="250px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button 
                        ID="btnClear" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text="ClearData" 
                        onclick="btnClear_Click" 
                        Font-Bold="True" 
                        Font-Size="X-Large" 
                        Height="50px"
                        Width="250px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </Table>



             </span>


    </div> 

</asp:Content>
```

and the code that is invoqued by the asp is the following:

```
   Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim gclass As New GlobalClass
    Dim employeeData As New Employee
    Dim intEmployee() As Integer
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirmPassword.Click
        If drpEmployee.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            ExeQuery("I")
        Else
            ExeQuery("U")
        End If
        clearFields()
    End Sub

    Sub ExeQuery(strMode As String)
        If txtRegularTime.Text <> "" Then
            Dim query As String = gclass.SPEmployeeCall(strMode, 1, txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtConfirmpassword.Text, _
                                                txtEmployee_id.Text, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, _
                                                 Convert.ToDouble(txtOverTime.Text), Convert.ToDouble(txtDoubleTime.Text), _
                                                 Convert.ToDouble(txtPartTime.Text), Convert.ToDouble(txtRegularTime.Text))
            gclass.ExecuteSP(query)
        End If
    End Sub



    Protected Sub txtRegularTime_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtRegularTime.TextChanged
        If Convert.ToDecimal(txtRegularTime.Text) > 0 Then
            txtDoubleTime.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRegularTime.Text * 2)
            txtOverTime.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRegularTime.Text * 1.5)
            txtPartTime.Text = 0
        End If
        txtPassword.Focus()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub txtPartTime_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPartTime.TextChanged
        If Convert.ToDecimal(txtPartTime.Text) > 0 Then
            txtDoubleTime.Text = 0
            txtOverTime.Text = 0
            txtRegularTime.Text = 0
        End If
        txtPassword.Focus()
    End Sub
    Sub clearFields()
        drpEmployee.SelectedIndex = 0
        checkboxDRPemployee()
        txtEmployee_id.Text = Nothing
        txtFirstName.Text = Nothing
        txtLastName.Text = Nothing
        txtUserName.Text = Nothing
        txtDoubleTime.Text = Nothing
        txtOverTime.Text = Nothing
        txtRegularTime.Text = Nothing
        txtPartTime.Text = Nothing
    End Sub

    Sub clearFields(dt As DataTable)
        txtEmployee_id.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1)
        txtFirstName.Text = dt.Rows(0)(2)
        txtLastName.Text = dt.Rows(0)(3)
        txtUserName.Text = dt.Rows(0)(8)
        txtDoubleTime.Text = dt.Rows(0)(5)
        txtOverTime.Text = dt.Rows(0)(4)
        txtRegularTime.Text = dt.Rows(0)(7)
        txtPartTime.Text = dt.Rows(0)(6)
        txtPassword.Text = dt.Rows(0)(9)
        txtConfirmpassword.Text = dt.Rows(0)(10)
    End Sub




    Protected Sub txtEmployeeUser_id_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtEmployee_id.TextChanged, txtUserName.TextChanged
        Dim intMode As Integer

        If sender Is txtEmployee_id Then
            intMode = 2
        ElseIf sender Is txtUserName Then
            intMode = 3
        End If

        Dim query As String = gclass.SPEmployeeCall("Q", intMode, txtUserName.Text, Nothing, Nothing, _
                                                    txtEmployee_id.Text, Nothing, Nothing, _
                                                    Nothing, Nothing, _
                                                    Nothing, Nothing)
        lblEmployeeID.Visible = True
        lblEmployeeID.Text = gclass.DatabaseMessages(query)
    End Sub



    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Session.Contents("Employee") Is Nothing Then
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
        Else
            employeeData = Session("Employee")
        End If
        If Not IsPostBack And drpEmployee.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            Session.Contents("EmployeeDDL") = gclass.LoadEmployeeAbsent(drpEmployee, 99)
        End If
        checkboxDRPemployee()
    End Sub


    Protected Sub drpEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drpEmployee.SelectedIndexChanged
        intEmployee = Session.Contents("EmployeeDDL")
        If drpEmployee.SelectedIndex <> 0 Then
            Dim query As String = gclass.SPEmployeeCall("Q", 7, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, intEmployee(drpEmployee.SelectedIndex), Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
            Dim dt As DataTable = gclass.Mysql_CreateDataTable(query)
            clearFields(dt)
        Else
            clearFields()
        End If



    End Sub

    Sub checkboxDRPemployee()
        If drpEmployee.SelectedIndex <> 0 Then
            CheckBox1.Enabled = True
            CheckBox1.Checked = False
        Else
            CheckBox1.Enabled = False
            CheckBox1.Checked = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        clearFields()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub txtpassword_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        If Not CheckBox1.Checked Then
            args.IsValid = (txtPassword.Text <> "")
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub txtConfirmpassword_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        If Not CheckBox1.Checked Then
            args.IsValid = (txtPassword.Text = txtConfirmpassword.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub chkChecked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        Dim thisValue As Boolean = CheckBox1.Checked


        txtPassword.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked
        txtConfirmpassword.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thank you in advance 
Kindest Regards
Douglas Leekam

Comment: Can you cut that right down to the minimal code which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely has something to do with `AutoPostBack="true"`

Try to debug by changing to:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkChecked"  />
```

Not sure what the functionality of your code is, but you might want to wrap page load code inside

```
 If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
// code currently in page load
 End If
```

Comment: Greetings, Thank you, i was testing what you said but part of the functionality of the checkbox is 
1) when checked
    set the enable property of the textboxt to false or true depending of the checked state

Comment: Greetings, Thank you, i was testing what you said but part of the functionality of the checkbox is 
1) when checked
    set the enable property of the textboxt to false or true depending of the checked state

so when i get rid of the AutoPostBack ="true" it doesnt execute the vbscript

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to check whether checkbox is checked or not based on value you can disable the control from javascript itself. You can use javascript onchange event to check checkbox value.